# "The nurse put a needle into the patient's blood vein"

Tags: phrase-request

Is it okay to say "The nurse put a needle into the patient's blood vein" or is there a better way of describing this usual action performed by nurses in hospital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to say "blood vein".  Vein alone will do.

See also "IV".

The  nurse put an IV in the patient's wrist | elbow.

The nurse inserted an IV in the patient's wrist | elbow.

The nurse placed an IV in the patient's wrist | elbow.

Comment: You don't say 'blood artery' either.

Comment: Unless you wish to alarm your barber shop customers.

Comment: The alarm will be over quickly.

Comment: Barber: It's not a ... razor cut? (suddenly) Razor, razor, cut, cut, blood, spurt, artery, murder... (controlling himself) Oh thank God, thank God. (sigh of relief) It's just a scissors.

Customer: Yes... (laughs, thinking the barber must be having a little joke)

Answer (score 1):

A better sentence is

> The nurse inserted a needle into the patient's vein.

We can't say "injected" or "injection" because the nurse may be taking a sample of blood: there is no reason given. Also no need for "blood vein" because that is what a vein is for: it carries blood.